# How to prevent PasswordTextField from clearing text when form is submitted?

Tags: java, html, forms, apache, wicket

I have a button, when I click this button, the form is submitted and the validation is made. If the the password is invalid, I'd like it to stay there after the form is submitted.

I tried to save the password in a var named `passwordStr` and then setting the model object of the PasswordTextField with this var, all this in the `onSubmit()` method of the form. Didn't work though.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Dont.do.it! The reason the field is clear is, that to fill it again, it must appear somewhere within the response of the request, which makes is horrible easy for attackers (think of XSS) to fetch it. However, you could validate via Ajax and only redirect, when the validation is sucessful, so the field isn't cleared at all :)

Comment: @KingCrunch Oh, I see. So it's for security reasons. Well, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `PasswordTextField#setResetPassword(false)`. Here's the JavaDoc:

> Flag indicating whether the contents of the field should be reset each time it is rendered.
>   If `true`, the contents are emptied when the field is rendered. This is useful for
>   login forms. If `false`, the contents of the model are put into the field. This is
>   useful for entry forms where the contents of the model should be editable, or resubmitted.